# C - data type conversion without computer

Tags: c, printf, short

I have a sample question from test from my school. Which way is the most simple for solving it on paper?

The question:
*Run-time system uses two's complement for representation of integers. Data type int has size 32 bits, data type short has size 16 bits. What does printf show?* (The answer is **ffffe43c**)

```
short int x = -0x1bc4; /* !!! short */

printf ( "%x", x );
```

Comment: This should be undefined behavior because you're feeding a `short` into a `%x`, which is a type mismatch.

Comment: @Dan argument passing automatically promotes to `int`, with sign extension. As the negative representation of integers is specified, I don't think it's undefined.

Comment: Oh, ok then, I'll buy that explanation.

Comment: Please don't put "[solved]" or anything else like that in your titles. If one of the answers worked for you, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which is how we mark questions as having been answered here.

Answer (score 1):

lets make it in two steps: 1bc4 = 1bc3 + 1

first of all we make this on long:

```
0 - 1 = ffffffff
```

then

```
ffffffff - 1bc3
```

this can be done by symbols

```
 ffffffff
-
 00001bc3
```

you will get the result you have

Comment: Nice, thank you! (I'd like to give you vote up, but I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `x` is negative take the two's complement of it which will yield:

```
2's(-x) = ~(x) + 1

2's(-0x1BC4) = ~(0x1BC4) + 1 => 0xE43C

0x1BC4 = 0001 1011 1100 0100
~0X1BC4 =1110 0100 0011 1011
+1 =     [1]110 0100 0011 1100 (brackets around MSB)
```

which is how your number is represented internally.

Now `%x` expects a 32-bit integer so your computer will sign-extend your value which copies the MSB to the upper 16 bits of your value which will yield:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0100 0011 1100 == 0xFFFFE43C
```

Comment: Oh, that's where the F's came from. Thank you